# Python Regex on repeated pattern and positive/negative lookarounds

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string, and I want to parse out the text in between everything that is of `r'~m~\d+~m~'` pattern.

```
'~m~883~m~{"m":"series_loading","p":["cs_BUrBYauwLKqR","s0","s0",1618109324],"t":1618109324}~m~88~m~{"m":"study_loading","p":["cs_BUrBYauwLKqR","rsi0","s0_rsi0",1618109324],"t":1618109324}'
```

Is there a regex that I can use in Python to achieve this result? I have tried lookarounds and non-capturing groups but was unable to achieve the expected results.

For clarity, this is the expected result:

```
[
    {"m":"series_loading","p":["cs_BUrBYauwLKqR","s0","s0",1618109324],"t":1618109324},
    {"m":"study_loading","p":["cs_BUrBYauwLKqR","rsi0","s0_rsi0",1618109324],"t":1618109324}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

split_strings = re.split('~m~\d+~m~', '~m~883~m~{"m":"series_loading","p":["cs_BUrBYauwLKqR","s0","s0",1618109324],"t":1618109324}~m~88~m~{"m":"study_loading","p":["cs_BUrBYauwLKqR","rsi0","s0_rsi0",1618109324],"t":1618109324}')[1:]

import json

result = [json.loads(s) for s in split_strings]
```

Comment: This works exactly as what I needed, but just to satisfy my own curiosity, is there a way I can achieve the same results with ```findall``` with a non-capturing group solution? So far, I have tried the following re.findall(r'~m~\d+~m~(\S+})(?:~|$)', msg_string)

Comment: @darkvalance no, non-capturing groups do not include the 'match' in the results but they still do consume it. this is really a `split` use case.